# Auto referesh of page using ajax on django server not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, django-views

We want to update some data/message on div part of Django view using HTML template. I have written AJAX call using JavaScript to read the file to get latest messages and reload the same in every 30 sec.

The information is not getting update on page.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
    <p id="demo"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.statusText;
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.name;
    //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Test";
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "{% static 'json_demo1.txt' %}", true);
xmlhttp.send();
setInterval(xmlhttp, 30000);
```

When json_demo.txt updated with some data it should be reflected on page. But in our case it is updating only once.

Comment: You need to wrap all those `xmlhttp` lines in a function, like `function update() { ... }`, then call `setInterval(update, 30000);`

Comment: After doing that, now no data is coming up. function update() { ...} update(); setInterval(update, 30000);